# Log in on OpenShift using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, openshift-origin

I have a docker container with jenkins deployed using OpenShift Origin.
Now I want to use Jenkins to build/test and deploy other OpenShift apps.
So I try to login on my OpenShift-server (from inside my jenkins) but than I get the following error. Can someone help me?

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/s2i-build-deploy/workspace
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
APP_HOSTNAME=http://test.apps.example.com
USER_NAME=admin
PASSWORD=admin
OSO_SERVER=ip.compute.internal:8443
DEVEL_PROJ_NAME=test
SERVICE=test
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1352752763797328747.sh
+ oc login -uadmin -padmin --server=ip.compute.internal:8443
error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The oc login-command is working when I'm performing directly in my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you need to also specify the CA that was used to sign the API server's certificate.  You will need to also specify --ca-file (check oc help options) with the ca.crt of the master in order to login.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/459#issuecomment-230398999) try:

`oc login $OPENSHIFT_URL --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true`